# Slepc shell matrices with multiple processes

Tags: mpi, petsc

I currently use explicit matrix storage for my generalized Eigenvalue equation of the form $AX = \lambda BX$ with eigenvalue lambda and eigenvector $X$. $A$ and $B$ are pentadiagonal by blocks, Hermitian and every block is Hermitian as well.

The problem is that for large simulations memory usage gets out of hand. I would therefore like to switch to Shell matrices. An added advantage would be that then I can avoid the duplication of a lot of information, as A and B are both filled through finite differences. I.e., the first derivative of a function X can be approximated by $X_i' = \frac{X_{i+1}-X_{i-1}}{\Delta}$, so that the same piece of information appears in two places. It gets (much) worse for higher orders.

When I try to implement this in Fortran, using multiple MPI processes that each contain a part of the rows of $A$ and $B$, I stumble upon the following issue: To perform matrix multiplication, one needs the vector information of $X$ from other ranks at the end of each rank's interval, due to the off-diagonal elements of $A$ and $B$.

I found a conceptual solution by using MPI all to all commands that pass the information from these "ghosted" regions to the ranks next-door. However, I fear that this might not be most portable, and also not too elegant.

Is there any way to automate this process of taking the information from ghost zones in Petsc / Slepc?

Comment: One of the greatest object of Petsc is the [DMDA structure](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/petsc-current/docs/manualpages/DM/DMDA.html) which represents a structured grid. You can get a local version of a vector including ghost nodes by using `DMGlobalToLocalBegin()`. You can then use `DMDAVecGetArrayDOF()` to manipulate a multidimensional and write the finite difference. Finally, you can perform the assembly after `DMDAVecRestoreArrayDOF() by `DMLocalToGlobalBegin()` See section 2.4 of Petsc's manual!

Comment: Thanks for this commend, Francis! The problem here, I think, is that in order to use shell matrices in Slepc (or Petsc) you have to define its operations on a vector in your own custom routine. This routine needs to take a vector, the matrix and produce an output vector. This input vector is generally not a DM vector, as far as I now? Or is it? Is there perhaps a way to enforce this?

Comment: If the vector comes from elsewhere, it is likely that it is not produced by a DMDA. You can try the function `VecGetDM()` to retreive the DMDA... but it will likely fail. Nevertheless, if local portions of the vector correspond to subarrays, and if the layout is consistent with that created by a DMDA, you can make a copy to a vector produced by the DMDA using either `VecCopy()` or a memcpy on the array retreived by VecGetArray()

Comment: That is a very interesting way of doing it. Indeed, VecGetDM failed, but I guess theworkaround would work. 

However, I decided that this would be slower than just usin MPI directly, for example usin all to all.

It works now, but is not nearly as elegant as I would have hoped. Haha.

Comment: By the way, I would accept this as an answer but I can't seem to do that with a comment.